# Delphi download multithreading

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

My initial question was misleading, I'll try to improve it:

I was able to write a small delphi programme, which is able to do a threaded download by using indy's idHTTP. It consists of 2 files:

- the form:

  ```
  interface

  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      Button1: TButton;
      Label1: TLabel;
      Button2: TButton;
      IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
      IdAntiFreeze1: TIdAntiFreeze;
      IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
      ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
      procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    private
      { Private-Deklarationen }
    public
      { Public-Deklarationen }
       procedure UpdateLabel(BytesDone: Integer);
       procedure UpdateProgressBar(AWorkCount: Int64);
       procedure InitProgressBar(AWorkCountMax: Int64);
       procedure ResetProgressBar;
    end;

  var
    Form1: TForm1;
    uStopDownloading: Boolean;

  implementation

  {$R *.dfm}

  uses Unit2;


  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    HTTPThread: TIdHTTPThread;
  begin
    HTTPThread := TIdHTTPThread.Create(True);
    HTTPThread.Url := 'https://www.bot-factory.de/tmp/lorem7.txt';
    HTTPThread.EncodedStr := '';
    HTTPThread.Filename := 'C:\test.txt';
    HTTPThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    HTTPThread.Resume;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
   idhttp.Disconnect;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.UpdateLabel(BytesDone: Integer);
  begin
    Label1.caption := format('%.0n',[extended(BytesDone+0.0)]) +' bytes loaded.';
  end;

  procedure TForm1.UpdateProgressBar(AWorkCount: Int64);
  begin
    ProgressBar1.Position := AWorkCount;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.InitProgressBar(AWorkCountMax: Int64);
  begin
    Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
    ProgressBar1.Max := AWorkCountMax;
    ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.ResetProgressBar;
  begin
   Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
   showmessage('Job is done');
  end;

  END.
  ```
- And the Thread-Unit:

  ```
  interface

  uses
    Classes, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, sysutils;

  type
    TIdHTTPThread = class(TThread)
    private
      FURL: AnsiString;
      FencodedStr: string;
      FFilename: AnsiString;
      FBytesDone,FProgress,FWorkCountMax: Int64;
      IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
      procedure OnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
      procedure OnWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Int64);
      procedure OnWorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
      procedure Updatelabel;
      procedure UpdateProgressBar;
      procedure InitProgressBar;
      procedure ResetProgressBar;
      procedure Disconnect;
    public
      Constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
      Destructor Destroy; override;
      property Url: AnsiString read FURL write FUrl;
      property encodedstr: String read FencodedStr write FencodedStr;
      property Filename: AnsiString read FFilename write FFilename;
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
    end;

  implementation

  uses
    Unit1; // Formular Unit

  constructor TIdHTTPThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
  begin
    inherited Create(Suspended);
    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    IdHTTP.OnWork := OnWork;
    IdHTTP.OnWorkBegin := OnWorkBegin;
    IdHTTP.OnWorkEnd := OnWorkEnd;
    //IdHTTP.Disconnect := Disconnect;
  end;

  destructor TIdHTTPThread.Destroy;
  begin
    IdHTTP.Free;
    inherited;
  end;

  procedure TIdHTTPThread.Execute;
  var
    DestStream: TFileStream;
  begin
    DestStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate);
    try
      IdHTTP.Get(Url, DestStream);
    finally
      DestStream.Free;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TIdHTTPThread.OnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
  begin
    FBytesDone := AWorkCount;
    FProgress := AWorkCount;
    Synchronize(Updatelabel);
    Synchronize(UpdateProgressBar);
  end;

  procedure TIdHTTPThread.OnWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Int64);
  begin
    FWorkCountMax := AWorkCountMax;
    Synchronize(InitProgressBar);
  end;

  procedure TIdHTTPThread.Disconnect;
  begin
    idhttp.Disconnect;
  end;

  procedure TIdHTTPThread.OnWorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
  begin
    Synchronize(ResetProgressBar);
  end;

  procedure TIdHTTPThread.Updatelabel;
  begin
    Form1.UpdateLabel(FBytesDone);
  end;

  procedure TIdHTTPThread.UpdateProgressBar;
  begin
    Form1.UpdateProgressBar(FProgress);
  end;

  procedure TIdHTTPThread.InitProgressBar;
  begin
    Form1.initProgressBar(FWorkCountMax);
  end;

  procedure TIdHTTPThread.resetProgressBar;
  begin
    Form1.resetProgressBar;
  end;

  END.
  ```

I have in fact 2 questions:

1. How can I interrupt the download of a (large) file ? I know that
   `idhttp.disconnect` should do the trick, but I do not know how to use it properly in my thread.
2. And furthermore: how can I use POST instead of GET?

I need to run this POST in a thread:

```
{++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//submit_post
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++}
Procedure submit_post(url_string,EncodedStr,filename:string);
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
  Params: TStringStream;
begin
  astream := TMemoryStream.create;
  Params := TStringStream.create('');
  Form1.IdHTTP.Request.Clear;
  Form1.IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := TRUE;

  try
    with Form1.IdHTTP do
    begin
      Params.WriteString(EncodedStr);
      Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
      try
        Response.KeepAlive := False;
        Post(url_string, params, astream);
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    astream.WriteBuffer(#0' ', 1);
    astream.Position := 0;
    astream.SaveToFile(filename);
  finally
    astream.Free;
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not really seeing a question here. But since it seems you're simply downloading files I'm not convinced you need 3 threads. See my answer to another question on this subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24090040/224704) for more detail.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @user Just to be clear on something I mentioned in my other answer.... I ***do recommend*** using **one** separate thread to do the download. But I would simply download all 10 files one after the other in that thread. The benefits of this are that: the main thread would then remain responsive, can show progress, and even provide an option to tell the download thread to abort if needed.

Comment: @Craig, I don't like the idea of a single threaded downloader. You can benefit from having multiple threads here. Think about a *slow server side connection* and how it can block your *single threaded pipeline*. It might happen that you'll wait ages for downloading e.g. a 1kB file just because the server serves you it slowly whilst you could utilize your bandwidth with other ones running in parallel.

Comment: I am with TLama on this, multiple thread would be more beneficial in this situation. One can always limit the number of thread to the number of cores.

Comment: @CraigYoung: I also agree.  A multithreaded downloader works just fine, and does not prevent all of the criteria you mentioned (responsive main thread, can show progress, and can be aborted).  Also consider if files are on different servers, there would be no reason to restrict the app to one download at a time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really a question.

Comment: JediVCL has a TJvURLGrabber. Ain't sure but i think it is multithreaded